# Breaking single responsibility

Tags: c#

I had a problem statement and my solution satisfy the requirement but I do not think it is good solution as it breaks Single responsibility requirement.Can someone suggest any better way to achieve the result.

I am new to programming but even I can say that i is not a good solution that supports OOPS.Kindly suggest any suggestion that can enhance the usability of solution.

**Question:**

Need to implement a simple promotion engine for a checkout process. Our Cart contains a list of single character SKU ids (A, B, C....) over which the promotion engine will need to run.

The promotion engine will need to calculate the total order value after applying the 2 promotion types buy 'n' items of a SKU for a fixed price (3 A's for 130) buy SKU 1 & SKU 2 for a fixed price ( C + D = 30 )

The promotion engine should be modular to allow for more promotion types to be added at a later date (e.g. a future promotion could be x% of a SKU unit price). For this coding exercise you can assume that the promotions will be mutually exclusive; in other words if one is applied the other promotions will not apply

Test Setup

```
Unit price for SKU IDs
A 50
B 30
C 20
D 15
```

Active Promotions

```
3 of A's for 130
2 of B's for 45
C & D for 30
```

Scenario A

```
1 * A 50
1 * B 30
1 * C 20
======
Total 100
```

Scenario B

```
5 * A 130 + 2*50
5 * B 45 + 45 + 30
1 * C 20
======
Total 370
```

Scenario C

```
3 * A 130
5 * B 45 + 45 + 1 * 30
1 * C -
1 * D 30
======
Total 280
```

My Solution:

**Product Class:**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Product
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }


        public Product(string id)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            switch (id)
            {
                case "A":
                    this.Price = 50m;

                    break;
                case "B":
                    this.Price = 30m;

                    break;
                case "C":
                    this.Price = 20m;

                    break;
                case "D":
                    this.Price = 2015m;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            Console.WriteLine("total number of order");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("enter the type of product:A,B,C or D");
                string type= Console.ReadLine();
                Product p = new Product(type);
                products.Add(p);
            }

            int totalPrice = GetTotalPrice(products);
            Console.WriteLine(totalPrice);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int GetTotalPrice(List<Product> products)
        {
            int counterofA = 0;
            int priceofA = 50;
            int counterofB = 0;
            int priceofB = 30;
            int CounterofC = 0;
            int priceofC = 20;
            int CounterofD = 0;
            int priceofD = 15;
            foreach (Product pr in products)
            {
                if (pr.Id == "A"||pr.Id=="a")
                {
                    counterofA=counterofA + 1;
                }
                if (pr.Id == "B"||pr.Id=="b")
                {
                    counterofB = counterofB + 1;
                }
                if (pr.Id == "C"||pr.Id=="c")
                {
                    CounterofC = CounterofC + 1;
                }
                if (pr.Id == "D" || pr.Id=="d")
                {
                    CounterofD = CounterofD + 1;
                }
            }
            int totalPriceofA = (counterofA / 3) * 130 + (counterofA % 3 * priceofA);
            int totalPriceofB = (counterofB / 2) * 45 + (counterofB % 2 * priceofB);
            int totalPriceofC = (CounterofC * priceofC);
            int totalPriceofD = (CounterofD * priceofD);
            return totalPriceofA + totalPriceofB + totalPriceofC + totalPriceofD;

        }
    }
}
```

**Working Solution:**

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELP2gV
```

[Fidder Solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELP2gV)

Comment: Probably better suited on Code Review? If it actually _works_ as expected, then it is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: I pasted in code review but it is downgraded without any reason.Not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 1):

Shortly I will take price calculation by type out of Product model and move it to ProductService. I will also move GetTotalPrice to ProductService.

ProductService will also get an interface called IProductService.

Finally I will make minor code clean up and styling.

This way you can make it easier testing your methods in ProductService and you have gathered method logic's in ProductService.

Let's look at the code:

Product model

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

ProductService interface:

```
public interface IProductService
{
    void GetPriceByType(Product product);
    int GetTotalPrice(List<Product> products);
}
```

ProductService class:

```
public void GetPriceByType(Product product)
{
    switch (product.Id)
    {
        case "A":
            product.Price = 50m;

            break;
        case "B":
            product.Price = 30m;

            break;
        case "C":
            product.Price = 20m;

            break;
        case "D":
            product.Price = 2015m;
            break;
    }
}

public int GetTotalPrice(List<Product> products)
{
    int counterOfA = 0;
    int priceOfA = 50;
    int counterOfB = 0;
    int priceOfB = 30;
    int counterOfC = 0;
    int priceOfC = 20;
    int counterOfD = 0;
    int priceOfD = 15;

    foreach (Product pr in products)
    {
        switch (pr.Id)
        {
            case "A":
            case "a":
                counterOfA += 1;
                break;
            case "B":
            case "b":
                counterOfB += 1;
                break;
            case "C":
            case "c":
                counterOfC += 1;
                break;
            case "D":
            case "d":
                counterOfD += 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    int totalPriceOfA = (counterOfA / 3) * 130 + (counterOfA % 3 * priceOfA);
    int totalPriceOfB = (counterOfB / 2) * 45 + (counterOfB % 2 * priceOfB);
    int totalPriceOfC = (counterOfC * priceOfC);
    int totalPriceOfD = (counterOfD * priceOfD);
    return totalPriceOfA + totalPriceOfB + totalPriceOfC + totalPriceOfD;
}
```

And some thing extra which is not part of the question, regarding your switch condition, you could use C# 8 Switch expressions and shorten it like:

```
product.Price = product.Id switch
{
    "A" => 50m,
    "B" => 30m,
    "C" => 20m,
    "D" => 2015m,
    _ => product.Price
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create a `Promotion Engine`, you need to add extra classes, such as:

- `Promotion` - to store `product.id` and the number of occurrences with promo-price
- `Order` - to store products bought by consumer

Then, you need to decide if promotions can be linked. If yes, then below LinqPad script is ready to use. If not, then you'll be in need to change algoritm accordingly. In case of only single promotion can be applied and it should be the highest rebate, then `decimal promoprice = promoprices.Max()` should be enough. ;)

I've added extra comments. Please, read them.

```
void Main()
{
    //create list of promotions
    //we need to add information about Product's count
    Dictionary<String, int> d1 = new Dictionary<String, int>();
    d1.Add("A", 3);
    Dictionary<String, int> d2 = new Dictionary<String, int>();
    d2.Add("B", 2);
    Dictionary<String, int> d3 = new Dictionary<String, int>();
    d3.Add("C", 1);
    d3.Add("D", 1);

    List<Promotion> promotions = new List<Promotion>()
    {
        new Promotion(1, d1, 130),
        new Promotion(2, d2, 45),
        new Promotion(3, d3, 30)
    };

    //create orders
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
    Order order1 = new Order(1, new List<Product>(){new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("B"), new Product("B"), new Product("C"), new Product("D")});
    Order order2 = new Order(2, new List<Product>(){ new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("A"),  new Product("B")});
    Order order3 = new Order(3, new List<Product>(){ new Product("A"), new Product("A"), new Product("D"), new Product("B"), new Product("B")});
    orders.AddRange(new Order[]{order1, order2, order3});
    //check if order meets promotion
    foreach(Order ord in orders)
    {
        List<decimal> promoprices = promotions
            .Select(promo => PromotionChecker.GetTotalPrice(ord, promo))
            .ToList();
        decimal origprice = ord.Products.Sum(x=>x.Price);
        decimal promoprice = promoprices.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine($"OrderID: {ord.OrderID} => Original price: {origprice.ToString("0.00")} | Rebate: {promoprice.ToString("0.00")} | Final price: {(origprice - promoprice).ToString("0.00")}");
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Product
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }


    public Product(string id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        switch (id)
        {
            case "A":
                this.Price = 50m;

                break;
            case "B":
                this.Price = 30m;

                break;
            case "C":
                this.Price = 20m;

                break;
            case "D":
                this.Price = 15m;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class Promotion
{
    public int PromotionID  { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> ProductInfo { get; set; }
    public decimal PromoPrice  { get; set; }

    public Promotion(int _promID, Dictionary<string, int> _prodInfo, decimal _pp)
    {
        this.PromotionID = _promID;
        this.ProductInfo = _prodInfo;
        this.PromoPrice = _pp;
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID  { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Order(int _oid, List<Product> _prods)
    {
        this.OrderID = _oid;
        this.Products = _prods;
    }
}

public static class PromotionChecker
{
    //returns PromotionID and count of promotions
    public static decimal GetTotalPrice(Order ord, Promotion prom)
    {
        decimal d = 0M;
        //get count of promoted products in order
        var copp = ord.Products
            .GroupBy(x=> x.Id)
            .Where(grp=> prom.ProductInfo.Any(y=>grp.Key==y.Key && grp.Count()>=y.Value))
            .Select(grp=> grp.Count())
            .Sum();
        //get count of promoted products from promotion
        int ppc = prom.ProductInfo.Sum(kvp=> kvp.Value);
        while(copp>= ppc)
        {
            d +=  prom.PromoPrice;
            copp -= ppc;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
//promotion: (2*B) and (C+D) => 45+30=75
OrderID: 1 => Original price: 195,00 | Rebate: 75,00 | Final price: 120,00
//promotion: (3*A) => 130*2=260
OrderID: 2 => Original price: 330,00 | Rebate: 260,00 | Final price: 70,00
//promotion: (2*B) => 45
OrderID: 3 => Original price: 175,00 | Rebate: 45,00 | Final price: 130,00
```

**Final note:** *It's just an idea!*

There's much to improve! I'd create `Promotions` class which would implements `IList` interface to store `List<Promotion>`. The same with `Orders`. Finally, i'd move `GetTotalPrice` method to the `Orders` class.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it can be solved with [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

In your case it can be:

```
interface IPack { decimal GetPrice(); }

class Cart : IPack
{
    AProductPack APack = new AProductPack();
    ...

    IEnumerable<IPack> packs = new []{ APack, ... };

    public decimal GetPrice() => packs.Sum(p=>p.GetPrice());

    public void AddProduct(Product p)
    {
        switch(p.Id)
        { 
            case "A": APack.ProductsCount++; break; 
            ...
        }
    }
}

class AProductPack : IPack
{
    public int ProductsCount { get; set; }
    public decimal GetPrice() => 130 * (ProductsCount / 3) + 50 * (ProductsCount % 3);
}
```

Which can be extended in future with any implementation you want. E.g.

```
class WeightPriceProductPack : IPack
{
    public WeightPriceProductPack(decimal itemPrice, decimal packPrice, int packSize){ ... }

    public int ProductsCount { get; set; }
    public decimal GetPrice() 
        => packPrice * (ProductsCount / packSize) + itemPrice * (ProductsCount % packSize);
}
```